# The radix sort algorithm may have different run-time for datas with different order?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

I am trying to implement the radix sort algorithm. 
I am using a linked list to store the elements to be sorted, then I throw each element to its bucket. This bucket is just a pointer, that will link the list of elements that belongs to its bucket.

I am testing with 10.000.000 and 100.000.000 integers numbers in interval [0, 1000000]. This numbers can be in crescent, decrescent and random order.

The run-time for 100.000.000 numbers in crescent and decrescent order is about 20 seconds. But for the same number of elements with random order 
the run-time is about 110 seconds.

As I understand it, this algorithm has the same complexity for any quality 
of the data to be sorted.

Anyone know why this is happening ?

This is my code:

```
    void radix(Number** numbers)
    {
        unsigned int i, k, e = 1;
        Number* bucket[10];
        Number* tail[10];
        Number* index;

        for(k = 0; k < 7; k++, e *= 10)
        {
            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) bucket[i] = tail[i] = NULL;

            index = *numbers;
            while(index != NULL)
            {
                i = (index->value / e) % 10;

                if(tail[i] == NULL)
                    bucket[i] = index;
                else
                    tail[i]->next = index;

                tail[i] = index;
                index = index->next; 
            }

            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                if(tail[i] != NULL)
                {
                    *numbers = bucket[i];
                    index = tail[i];
                    for(i++; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        if(tail[i] != NULL)
                        {
                            index->next = bucket[i];
                            index = tail[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            index->next = NULL;
        }
    }
```

where `Number` is:

```
typedef struct number
{
    unsigned int value;
    struct number* next;
} Number;
```

Comment: it may have the same complexity, that doesnt mean it has the same run time.

Comment: But if is the same data, just with different order, this can affect a lot ? 20 to 110 seconds is too much  for the same data.

Comment: @X0R40 No, things like branch prediction fails (or cache misses, for that matter) can easily cause large performance differences just from reordering the data.

Comment: @IskarJarak I ended up including a small section on branch misprediction after seeing your comment. It slipped my mind in focus of just cache misses. Hope you don't mind !

Comment: @Ike Of course I don't mind! A better answer is a better answer :)

Comment: In most sorting algorithms,  if being sorted ascending, then the worst case is usually where the data starts out sorted descending.   A lot of this has to do with the number of swaps that must be made.   Although, cache misses and branch prediction and locality of data also play an important part in making the execution time longer.

Comment: @user3629249 Radix is a bit unusual in that sense, I think, in that it's a linear time algorithm involving binning instead of swapping. But that's a very good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is probably going to be related to memory access and locality of reference.

Ascending/descending order has a regular pattern to it that is likely to have greater temporal locality, not so much with respect to the buckets but likely more with respect to the way linked list nodes are used for numbers (especially if they aren't contiguous).

For instance, if we take the input:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, ...
```

We cycle through from bucket 0 to bucket 9 and then back to bucket 0. When we come back to bucket 0, we're accessing a `number` node which was accessed fairly recently (just 9 iterations ago) which is likely to be cached into a faster, smaller form of memory.

If we use a random ordering, who knows when we'll come back to bucket 0? As a result, there's a greater likelihood where we have long spans moving data from DRAM to cache before we come back to the memory used for the number at head of any given bucket. The result can translate to more of such former `number` nodes being evicted from the cache, and more cache misses when we come back to such a bucket.

Branch mispredictions could also be consuming a bit of time with respect to the irregular ordering. Profiling should help narrow the cause.

One possible thing to try if you are actually memory-bottlenecked is to turn your buckets into, say, unrolled lists to which you deep copy the numbers. That will make it so you no longer access the memory for previously-inserted numbers which could have been inserted many iterations back (a potentially large variable due to the random ordering). With that we start to get back some of the temporal locality (and possibly spatial locality if the numbers were contiguously allocated) we would otherwise lose with this kind of linked list representation. It then becomes about reusing the contiguous memory of the buckets (for which there are only 10) instead of elements within buckets with variable strides in between. We also get spatial locality within the buckets with an unrolled representation.

> But if is the same data, just with different order, this can affect a
>   lot ? 20 to 110 seconds is too much for the same data.

Memory efficiency can make differences in the orders of magnitudes. http://lwn.net/Articles/250967/

I'm not an expert in this subject (more of a "profile it and try to optimize based on guidelines" type), but based on past results I've gotten from memory optimizations, I would often put them on par in terms of effect with algorithmic optimizations. Exceptions would be when the difference in complexity is gross (ex: linearithmic vs. quadratic), but even a linearithmic algorithm can very feasibly beat a linear one with very large inputs if the former is significantly more cache-friendly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand how can I turn my buckets into "unrolled lists" to get rid (probably) of fail branch prediction or cache misses.

Comment: Kind of like your basic linked list idea -- but instead of storing one `value`, you might store, say, 32 values and maybe a `size` variable containing how many numbers are being occupied by the node. Then you link the arrays together.

Comment: To then insert to one of these unrolled nodes, simply do like: `values[num++] = val;` ... unless num is 32, at which point you allocate a new unrolled node, link it with the previous, and set the first value.

Comment: It's a little wasteful if you have an unrolled list with 1 element storing the capacity of 32 elements, but naturally it's significantly more compact if you have a million elements or so since we're using 1/32nd of the amount of memory for list pointers (assuming an unrolled size of 32).

Comment: The unrolled list, for a big container, should be slightly over 4 bytes per element, while the regular linked list is typically about 16 bytes per element on 64-bit (4-byte int + 8-byte pointer + 4-byte padding). So it's about 1/4th the size of the linked list.

Comment: Imagine a regular singly-linked list like `[1]->[2]->[3]->[4]->null`. And let's assume an unrolled size of just 2. It would look like this: `[12]->[34]->null`. It's like a bastard between an array and linked list -- it's "linked arrays".

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Sorry, I've never heard about unrolled list. Now this makes sense.

Comment: It's a very useful structure for this kind of stuff where it gives you some of those kinds of qualities of linked lists but also some of the locality of reference that we typically get with arrays.

Comment: Computers tend to kind of grab handfuls of slower memory and cache them into faster memory.. from all the way to paging, say, 4 kilobyte chunks from secondary storage (disk, e.g) to DRAM... then DRAM to a hierarchy of cache lines all the way up to a 64-byte L1 cache line.. and then to, say, a teeny 64-bit GP register. Because it grabs all this memory in chunks, things tend to go faster when you use the memory in the surrounding chunk before it gets evicted from the faster memory -- that's why arrays tend to be quite nice -- we can grab their memory by the handfuls and use the surrounding data.

Comment: It's really pretty simple. When consecutive nodes in memory initially contain data in a random order, by the time the links have been changed so the data are sorted, traversing them touches memory in a random order. Random order is bad for cache performance at all levels of the memory hierarchy. A factor of 6 going from consecutive to random order is not bad. Your machine must have a pretty good memory subsystem.

Comment: I think even the machine has a pretty good memory subsystem, can occur cache miss. Because the machine do not predict in which order (if the order does not has a pattern) you will access the node.

Comment: @X0R40 Yes, though from the memory hierarchy standpoint, you can help it out quite a bit. The effective "prediction" there is that memory is often accessed contiguously within aligned chunks, and/or that these chunks are accessed more than once prior to eviction. So one of the first ways typically to help improve execution times is to kind of bunch the memory together to improve the odds that the same chunk of memory will be accessed more than once prior to eviction. Spatial locality is still basically about accessing the same chunk (even though it's a different element within that chunk).